# Majorana Fermions representation of Klein factors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory, bosonization

In Abelian Bosonization Klein Factors are introduced as raising and lowering operators which connect Hilbert spaces with different numbers of particles. 
Also for more than one species of bosons, the Klein Factors obey fermionic anticommutation relations (See for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275).

At many differnt points in the literature one reads that in the Thermodynamic limit the Klein factors can be mapped to Majorana fermions (See for example
[this book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=efm6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=klein+factors+majorana+fermions&source=bl&ots=54aIwl-7lk&sig=htpAMEzFOGz97TxgRu2IJb7O8Yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1oeyl5-HPAhWDbxQKHcyJDhgQ6AEIRDAE#v=onepage&q=klein%20factors%20majorana%20fermions&f=false), page 185).

I have two questions:

1) How do I proof the mapping between Klein Factors and Majorana operators precisely and why do I need the thermodynamic limit? Also a Majorana fermion is its own antiparticle ($\gamma=\gamma^{\dagger}$). How is this consistent with the Klein factors being creation and annihilation operators?

2) Often people tend to ignore Klein factors. In regards to this point I have the following question: Suppose I am given the following "superconducting" Hamiltonian with two fermionic fields $c$ and $d$: 
$$
H
=
\int\mathrm{d}x
\left[
c^{\dagger}(x)d^{\dagger}(x)
\right]
+
\text{H.c.}
$$
Now I am introducting bosonic modes via 
$$
c^{\dagger}=\frac{\eta_{c}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{2i\phi_{c}}
\qquad 
d^{\dagger}=\frac{\eta_{d}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-2i\phi_{d}}
$$
I am now interpreting $\eta_{c}$ and $\eta_{d}$ as Majorana fermions. 
Now I  am bosonizing $H$. This gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H
&=
\frac{
1}{2\pi}
\int\mathrm{d}x \ 
\eta_{c}\eta_{d}
e^{2i(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})}
+
\eta_{d}\eta_{c}
e^{-2i(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})}
\\
&=
i\eta_{c}\eta_{d}
\frac{
1}{\pi}
\int\mathrm{d}x \ 
\sin\left(
2(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})
\right)
\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now I can argue within the Majorana picture that $i\eta_{c}\eta_{d}$
is the Fermion parity of the complex fermion mode composed of the 
Majoranas $\eta_{c}$ and $\eta_{d}$. So when I am working in a fixed 
parity subspace, I can always ignore the Klein factors. Is this line of reasoning correct? Many people ignore the Klein factors from the beginning. If I would have set $\eta_{c}=\eta_{d}=1$ right from the start, the bosonized Hamiltonian would look like this: 
 \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H
&=
\frac{
1}{2\pi}
\int\mathrm{d}x \ 
e^{2i(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})}
+
e^{-2i(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})}
\\
&=
\frac{
1}{\pi}
\int\mathrm{d}x \ 
\cos\left(
2(\phi_{c}-\phi_{d})
\right)
\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now my question is: Is this approach also valid? Does it matter whether I get a $\sin$ or a $\cos$?

I am looking forward to your responses.